# Understanding Leibniz formula: $D^n (f g) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}f D^kg$

Tags: calculus

I would like some clarification for better understanding of Leibniz formula: $$D^n (f g) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}f D^kg$$

If I use the formula with the following expression: $f(x)= x^3e^x$

$$D^n (f g) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}x^3 D^k e^x = \binom{n}{0} 6e^x + \binom{n}{1} 6x e^x + \binom{n}{2} 3x^2e^x + \binom{n}{3} x^3 e^x$$

But when using the commutative law I get a different result...

$$D^n (gf) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}e^x D^k x^3 = \binom{n}{0} e^x x^3 + \binom{n}{1} e^x 3x^2 + \binom{n}{2} e^x 6x + \binom{n}{3} e^x6$$

Since my question was to calculate $D^nf$ of $f(x) = x^3e^x$ I get two different expressions depending on which "order" I use which seems strange...

Comment: It seems that you are missing the following: $ {n \choose k}=  {n \choose {n-k}} $

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Luis. Please explain what you mean in a little bit more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$D^n (gf) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}e^x D^k x^3 = \binom{n}{0} e^x x^3 + \binom{n}{1} e^x 3x^2 + \binom{n}{2} e^x 6x + \binom{n}{3} e^x6$$

Second expression you wrote  is correct but the first formula you wrote you  made mistake.
Let me show where you made mistake

$$D^n (f g) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}x^3 D^k e^x \neq \binom{n}{0} 6e^x + \binom{n}{1} 6x e^x + \binom{n}{2} 3x^2e^x + \binom{n}{3} x^3 e^x$$

The first expression you wrote  must be:

$$D^n (f g) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}x^3 D^k e^x =\binom{n}{0} \frac{d^n(x^3)}{dx^n} e^x + \binom{n}{1} \frac{d^{n-1}(x^3)}{dx^{n-1}} e^x+\binom{n}{2} \frac{d^{n-2}(x^3)}{dx^{n-2}} e^x +....+\binom{n}{n-3} \frac{d^3(x^3)}{dx^3}e^x + \binom{n}{n-2} \frac{d^2(x^3)}{dx^2}e^x+\binom{n}{n-1} \frac{d(x^3)}{dx}e^x+\binom{n}{n} x^3e^x   $$

To use the fact:  $$\frac{d^m(x^3)}{dx^m}=0$$where $m>3$

You can get

$$D^n (f g) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}x^3 D^k e^x =\binom{n}{n-3} \frac{d^3(x^3)}{dx^3}e^x + \binom{n}{n-2} \frac{d^2(x^3)}{dx^2}e^x+\binom{n}{n-1} \frac{d(x^3)}{dx}e^x+\binom{n}{n} x^3e^x   $$

To use the fact: $$\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

$$D^n (f g) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} D^{n-k}x^3 D^k e^x =\binom{n}{3} \frac{d^3(x^3)}{dx^3}e^x + \binom{n}{2} \frac{d^2(x^3)}{dx^2}e^x+\binom{n}{1} \frac{d(x^3)}{dx}e^x+\binom{n}{0} x^3e^x   $$

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation!

Comment: @LukasArvidsson You are welcome. I am very glad that my answer  helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the RHS of your equations for $D^n(fg)$ and $D^n(gf)$ have the exact same $n$ functions and $n$ coefficients, but $D^n(gf)$ has the functions arranged in the reverse order. If we can establish that the original sequence of coefficients is equal to the sequence of coefficients *in reverse order*, we'll have established the desired equality. This is the goal.

As @Luis says, what we need is
\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}. 
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Note that the LHS of $(1)$ is our sequence of coefficients in the original order of $D^n(fg)$, and the RHS of $(1)$ is the reversed sequence of coefficients! Since $(1)$ says they're equal, we've established what we set out to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Much appreciated.